# Why Mysql does not find records that exists. It is about Lat&Lng database search

Tags: mysql

what could possible be the reason for Mysql does not find records that exists. It is about Lat&Lng database search. I have this simple query:

```
select id from addresses where lat = "42.5632172" and lng = "27.5266380"
```

which returns 0 results but its obvious that record exists.
Here is my database structure and records:
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue with sample data in a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT)?

Comment: Just a hint: comparing floats and double is often some kind of a lucky bet. Especially for geo data it is easy to convert them to integers before storing to the database. In that Case you can also define the precision you need by cuttin of the last digits if not needed.

Comment: Not sure if succeed with the fiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/SrqK8Mzf

Comment: @Thallius By the way changing Lat Lng field type to varchar helps but not sure if this won't deliver further problems

Comment: @Europeuser no that makes no sense, since in the most cases you like to work calculate with the data

Comment: @Europeuser You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since data type of your `lat` and `lng` columns is `float` which is not a precision data type, so comparing on this data type often lead to unexpected result.  It's better to use some tolerance when comparing values of these `float` columns.

```
 SELECT id 
 FROM addresses 
 WHERE ABS(lat - 42.5632172) <= 0.0000001 
       AND ABS(lng - 27.5266380) <= 0.0000001
```

But it's much better if you could change data type of your columns to precision number data type, such as DECIMAL.

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fR3hXCTi).

Comment: This should be avoided, as it makes the query non-sargable. If you need to take this approach use BETWEEN.

Comment: I accept as correct answer the suggestion to change the column type to decimal